# LowerBound in multiset stl

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, multiset

I was trying to find how many element are less than a certain X in a multiset by using:

```
mset.lower_bound(X) - mset.begin()
```

But it didn't work. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use:

```
std::distance(mset.begin(), mset.lower_bound(X));
```

To make it robust, use:

```
size_t count = 0;
auto found = mset.lower_bound(X);
if ( found != mset.end() )
{
   count = std::distance(mset.begin(), found);
}
```

Comment: But its linear in complexity :(

Comment: @Swatak, I don't think you can get around that with a `multiset`.

Comment: @Swatak: multiset usually doesn't have any way to count range sizes except for linear anyway, so this isn't slower than any other way.

Answer (score 3):

If computing the number of items below a lower bound is done frequently, and items are inserted seldom, you might get better performance using a `std::vector` and keeping it sorted.

Particularly if T is moveable.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>



auto insert(std::vector<std::string>& v, std::string s)
{
    auto lb = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), s);
    v.insert(lb, std::move(s));
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    insert(v, "goodbye");
    insert(v, "world");
    insert(v, "cruel");

    auto count = std::distance(v.begin(), std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), "goodbye"));
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

}
```

> but why still use std::distance with vector?

Because we might change our mind if we choose to profile with different container types, so it's better to be idiomatic. The standard library contains specialisations to ensure that the idiom is optimal:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<class Range, class Value, class Pred = std::less<>>
auto lower_bound(Range&& range, Value&& v, Pred&& pred = Pred())
{
    return std::lower_bound(std::begin(range), std::end(range),
                            std::forward<Value>(v),
                            std::forward<Pred>(pred));
}

template<class Container>
auto insert(Container&& v, std::string s)
{
    auto lb = lower_bound(v, s);
    v.insert(lb, std::move(s));
}

template<class Range, class OutIter>
auto copy(Range&& range, OutIter dest)
{
    return std::copy(std::begin(range), std::end(range), dest);
}

auto test = [](auto&& container)
{
    insert(container, "goodbye");
    insert(container, "world");
    insert(container, "cruel");

    auto count = std::distance(std::begin(container), lower_bound(container, "goodbye"));
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    copy(container, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

};

int main()
{
    test(std::vector<std::string>{});
    test(std::multiset<std::string>{});
}
```

Comment: If using a `vector` wouldn't `operator-` work since it's a random access iterator (i.e., `std::distance` isn't required anymore)?

Comment: @JamesAdkison When used on *RandomAccessIterator*, `std::distance` complexity is constant.

Comment: @JamesAdkison true but it's more idiomatic and portable should you decide to change the container type later.

Comment: @Holt Perfect, that would have been a follow-up question of mine. That completely negates any reason to prefer `operator-` over `std::distance`.